How can I set up an RPC node for the Solana testnet
There are only articles to start with a local validator. I don't want to start any local validator; I want to run an RPC node for the real testnet. How can I do it? I can't find any documentation regarding it. I only found this: https://nodes.guru/testnets/solana/setup-guide/en, but it’s still not working and showing the error:
[2024-09-27T13:39:43.745284020Z ERROR solana_validator] Failed to start validator: "failed to load bank: AccountsFile error: I/O error: Disk quota exceeded (os error 122), full snapshot archive: /efs/solana_node/ledger/remote/snapshot-294878673-a6AxTznrH1mgMp6UhcP8Y7x4LXswTk7Grob8TFaRtSm.tar.zst, incremental snapshot archive: /efs/solana_node/ledger/remote/incremental-snapshot-294878673-294889827-D1ggzreWHaL2uYCP9bT9BK99vyMaUWBZo7CakF191EFj.tar.zst"

Please help me set up a testnet node. Thanks. Please don’t delete my message; just let me know in which chanel to ask, as the Solana exchange is super slow and no one is responding there.
//solana discord mods removed me for this question, no freedom of speed.

Solana Labs has a docs page (which will likely be moved soon) about how to setup a node against testnet: https://docs.solanalabs.com/operations/setup-a-validator
The error of a disk quota exceeded might persist even if you follow these directions though. Be sure to provision enough disk space in your VM.

Your best bet is probably to test directly on devnet if that's what you want to do. If you're using Anchor you can configure your tests for devnet:
[provider]
cluster = "devnet"

Running anchor tests in this environment will deploy your program to devnet.
If using Solana cli:
solana config set --url https://api.devnet.solana.com
You would have to manually deploy your program to devnet.
You need a lot of hardware to run an RPC node, so unless you have a machine with 256Gb of RAM sitting around and a lot of money to burn you probably aren't running your own validator. Devnet is free to use and is the best representation of mainnet.

No, I don't want to run the devnet, I have the highly optimized EC2, and I don't have any issue with money n all, I just want to run testnet node, a simple RPC node.
